# Need to match any string that contains [a-z0-9\x20] but with no spaces at the start or end and no double spaces

Tags: regex

So far I have

```
^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\x20]+[a-z0-9]+$
```

Which matches all criteria except not matching double spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-z0-9](?: ?[a-z0-9])*$
```

As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/afkMiB4wRI)

```
a_bc   # match (underscore '_' represents space)
abc    # match
a_     # no match
_a     # no match
a__b   # no match
```

(You can replace the whitespace after the `?:` with `\x20` if you have to)

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working for me (not matching double spaces). I should have specified I'm using php if that matters. I used \x20 because I wanted to be certain I was only matching spaces and no other white spaces.

Comment: I tried your solution again and I can't duplicate my earlier failure. I may have copy pasted incorrectly - been a long day. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should work:

```
^[a-z0-9]+((\x20)?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

This will mean you can have letter or number at the start, one or more times, followed by a block containing a space 0 or 1 times, followed by 1 or more letters or numbers, which can be included 0 or more times.

Edit: I think this should work. Can only have 0 or 1 spaces in between blocks of letters/numbers.

Comment: Fails to match (supposedly) valid string `aa a`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(\x20[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

One or more letter or numbers, followed by a space & one or more letters/numbers, repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: Strange, it wasn't working here. Must've copied and pasted wrong.